# Struts2 TDD - Testing chaining - how to prevent dispatcher from doing the chain?

Tags: junit, struts2, tdd, action, chain

I'm running a JUnit test - testing an action that chains.

We have a large internal testing framework (inherits from StrutsTestCase) that sets up everything for an action to work during a test but when chaining to a new action - the new (chained) action isn't setup correct and internal code runs into NULLs.

I believe the test should only test for the correct result from the action call and should *not* test the chained action.

**My Q: I'm looking for a way to disable chaining while testing. Can the Dispatcher created in StrutsTestCase.setUp() be configured to handle chaining differently (eg. do nothing)?**

Wish I could avoid chaining but that's the way it's done here.

EDIT - Here is code:
Action:

```
  @Action(value = SUBMIT, results = { 
        @Result(name = SUCCESS, type = "chain", params = { "actionName", "myActionName", "namespace", "/myNameSpace" }) })
public String submitForm() throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, IOException     {

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Test:

```
    @Test
public void testStuff() throws Exception {
    setupAction();
    prepareForValidUser();
    this.actionUnderTest.getModel().setUpSomeStuff(someSetupValue);
    final String result = this.proxy.execute();
    assertEquals("Result not the expected result", SUCCESS, result);
}
```

The test relies heavily on a nice testing framework; proxy.execute() is what runs the action (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxy.class).

Comment: If you want to test only the result from action call then you should setup your test not to execute any result not only chain. And yes, use chain only when you know what you are doing and what for you are doing it.

Comment: It's difficult to tell you what kind of use case do you coding. Post the code related to your problem.

Comment: @AleksandrM Yes I agree but I simply don't know how to set it up so it does not execute any result.

Comment: @RomanC I added some (simplified) code. Hope that helps you see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @Skychan: Maybe you just need to fix this npe.

Comment: The test method sets up the Action such as creating a session, etc. If the struts framework chains, it instantiates a whole new Action object that my test code doesn't have the chance to "set up". So that's why I hope to disable execution of the result, because I feel test code doesn't need to test the chain code since there is a test method for that action already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to simply call the action method directly instead of relying on the struts framework to execute the action for you.

This:

```
final String result = this.proxy.execute();
```

becomes

```
final String result = this.actionUnderTest.myActionMethod();
```

This worked well for me! Doing this meant that nothing handled/executed on the result of the action method (eg. no chaining occurred).

Comment: This does work. The thing to remember is that prepare() is not called. You can and should call actionUnderTest.prepare() in your test prior to calling myActionMethod().